# WEB API - Аналог CreateElement

Tags: javascript, webapi

Когда-то, где-то, читал про API, которое является аналогом `document.createElement` - не могу ни вспомнить название, ни найти, а гугл выдает тонны информации по `Jquery`

ПодскАжите?

Comment: web api это серверная часть, createElement клиентская, они никак не связаны. Возможно ты смотрел что-то про расширение Html хелпера

Comment: @Grundy, имеется ввиду что-то из этого https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API . Если я не правильно формулирую вопрос - можешь подправить?

Comment: тогда ты что-то не понял: createElement - Это и есть webapi

Comment: а также, не исключено, что ты имел ввиду [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Comment: @Grundy, нашел в истории браузера - `element.insertAdjacentHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
| метод                             | описание                                  |
|-----------------------------------|-------------------------------------------|
| `document.createElement`          | создаёт элемент                           |
| `document.createElementNS`        | например для `svg`                        |
| `document.createDocumentFragment` | создаёт `DocumentFragment`                |
| `document.createTextNode`         | создаёт текстовую ноду (`html` как текст) |
| `document.createComment`          | создёт комментарий                        |
|                                   |                                           |
| `document.createAttribute`        | создаёт атрибут например `style`, `class` |
| `document.createAttributeNS`      | например для `svg`                        |
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document

так же рекомендую посмотреть на вот эту троицу

```
let el: HTMLElement

el.insertAdjacentElement
el.insertAdjacentHTML
el.insertAdjacentText
```

да, и как верно заметил Grundy есть ещё отдельная тема - кастомные элементы